# Regex C++: extract substring between tags

Tags: c++, regex

I would like to extract a some substring between two tags.
Example: `<column r="1"><t b="red"><v>1</v></t></column>`
I would like to get: `<t b="red"><v>1</v></t>`

I don't want to use boost or other libs. Just standard stuffs from C++, except CERN's ROOT lib, with TRegexp, but I don't know how to use it...

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of what you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3959454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **shouldn't** be using regexes to try to match html, but, for this special case, you could do:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

// Your string
std::string str = "<column r="1"><t b=\"red\"><v>1</v></t></column>";

// Your regex, in this specific scenario
// Will NOT work for nested <column> tags!
std::regex rgx("<column.*?>(.*?)</column>");
std::smatch match;

// Try to match it
if(std::regex_search(str.begin(), str.end(), match, rgx)) {
  // You can use `match' here to get your substring
};
```

As Anton said above: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).